# What does KF mean next to a resistance value?

Tags: resistance, schematics

I was browsing schematics for SC8915 and on the drawing many resistors are labeled with KF next to the resistance value. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: I guess, K is for kilo and F for film.

Comment: Maybe the designer tried to get clever and show \$\Omega\$ on some of the resistors and Orcad doesn't support that encoding. Just a guess. You often see 'W' on .pdf files for similar reasons.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany Not All resistor are like that. For example there is 64KF resistor and next to him 62K. I started wondering if that is not the tolerance marked with F.

Comment: Possibly, I would be more convinced if I knew the function of the resistors and if it justified a tighter (eg. 1%) tolerance. Curiously 64 is not an E96 series value.

Comment: R14 and R19 are a feedback voltage divider. So... F for 'metal film', typical for a 1% resistor.

Comment: @hacktastical F is also the code for 1% like J is for 5%.

Comment: Ya got me on that one. Never seen that notation on a schematic until now. Is there some standard for this?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe someone should put an answer.